# ASP.NET Web API - How to handle exception propagation between two or more Web APIs?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with two or more ASP.NET Web APIs. One of them sends a request to the other and gets a response to be processed. It is a chain of response-request calls.
There is a recommended answer that suggests to create an ExceptionFilterAttribute to handle the exceptions in Web API and send a response with some properties data about the error:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new HandleApiExceptionAttribute());
        // ...
    }
}

public class HandleApiExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var request = context.ActionContext.Request;

        var response = new
        {
             //Properties go here...
        };

        context.Response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
    }
}
```

In this case, the client gets the response and handles the exception.

In the context where I'll have two or more Web APIs that communicate between them, if a business rule exception arises (for example invalid parameters, invalid data, no results found) I'll reply a json response with my error message. 
What is the best approach to handle this error propagation between two or more web APIs?

1. My first approach would be to have a set of exceptions (custom exception class), so JSON response will be parsed into this class and will be switched in final client to display a friendly message to user. In this case, the JSON response will only be propagated between all the web APIs. All web APIs and final client will share a common exceptions library to identify the exception type.
2. Send and propagate only "string" messages between Web APIs and final client switch/match these strings to respective methods to show friendly messages for final user. It seems this will cause duplicate exception code in each web api and isn't a clean solution.
3. Another clean and best practice to share Business Rule JSON exceptions between Web APIs to avoid duplicity and string message dependency ?

Comment: Will you call your other Web API through HttpClient or through call the web API c# class directly ?

Comment: through an HttpClient

Comment: @AlbertoMontellano I feel your pain, I am in the same situation having the same questions as you. Did you found any good solution so you could paste a bit code here? :-)